# ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation filter wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm updating my rails app from a minor version to another one `rails (6.0.1)` -> `rails (6.0.3.5)` and it seems that `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation.filter` method as changed from `expect 1 argument` -> `expect 0 argument`. I can't find a place which explain why or the actual function signature. Any help?

I use to call: `@obj.filter(params[:filter])` which triggers now an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) in `filter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to an update of ruby version. With ruby `2.7` they introduced a `filter` function which didn't exist before on `Array`. I had another `filter` method declared in a concern for model, but Rails is converting my active record object to array and calling `Array.filter` method on it instead of the one declared in my Concern. Changing the name of the function in the Concern made the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can check what's the origin of `filter` by using the `method` method (ha ha)

(I'll use `User` as an example)

```rb
User.all.method(:filter)
```

will return

```rb
#<Method: User::ActiveRecord_Relation(Enumerable)#filter()>
```

this means that `filter` comes from `Enumerable` module.
Now if we check the docs: https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Enumerable/filter it looks like it indeed doesn't accept any arguments. You can only pass a block to it and that's what I would suggest doing.

Why it used to work before? Unsure, maybe you were overriding this method using some gems or custom code?

Comment: thanks! I found an answer: The error is due to an update of ruby version. With ruby 2.7 they introduced a `filter` function which didn't exist before on `Array`. 
I had another `filter` method declared in a concern for model, but Rails is converting my active record object to array and calling `Array.filter` method on it instead of the one declared in my Concern. Changing the name of the function in the Concern made the trick!

Comment: Yeah, seem like before `filter` didn't exist in that context. glad you have it working now :)